# Write Long Raw bmp file to Oracle Databse using Java

Tags: java, oracle, long-integer, bmp

I'm trying to save a bmp file to a long raw column in a legacy oracle database using java, but i does not work well. This is the code i used:

```
InputStream input2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesArchivo);
String sql = "UPDATE firma_legal SET " +
                     "      firma = ? " +
                     "WHERE cod_unicom = 1120";
OraclePreparedStatement  stat =
                (OraclePreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stat.setBinaryStream(1, input2, (int)archivo.length());
stat.executeUpdate();
input2.close();
```

The code execute well, but when i see in the database, it does not update the row that i want, instead, it put this string "BMF;".

[image: Row updated]

How can i do to insert this file into long raw column?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the values `archivo.length()`, is that equals 4?

or

There or only 4 bytes available in `input2`, try `input2.available()` to check out.

Comment: Hi Ronson, the length is 15895, i didn't put the rest of the code for simplicity, but i checked it before write it to the database